# jQuery scrollTo on submit

Tags: jquery, scrollto

so after numerous hours of plugging away, I'm still scratching my head at how to accomplish this (quite simple) task.

On this page : [www.bassworx.com/matrix](http://www.bassworx.com/matrix)

I want it to scroll down to the #results area, upon clicking submit on the input button. I have tried to accomplish this with scrollTo and JSlideto, I have a feeling I should be able to do this with either of them, as the examples are very much what I want to happen.

Can somebody please take a look at the page in question, and help me sort this out? It's beginning to really give me a headache, and I'm almost certain I'm just missing some minor syntax or something.

Comment: You'll get better answers by showing your code.

Comment: Neither of your script lines target your buttons, or is there another script I'm missing that does?

Comment: So you'd like us to trawl thru your wordpress site figuring out what is wrong with your plugins. Good luck with that! Try replicating the problem in a simple [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) so it's possible to see your code without having to read five yards of code. Also, Daedalus is correct, there are no elements with the ID "default" or "nohighlight" ??

Comment: I'm asking you to check out the code on ONE page, that isn't even part of the wordpress portion of the site, and everything in question is fairly easily found. I have tried jslideto, and scrollTo, as of now, none of them are implemented, and I want a fresh start.

Comment: I removed all the previous script, and am starting fresh. Where should I begin ?

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea where the `goToByScroll()` function came from but props to the guy who did it. Not completely sure this is what you want but it works the way I think you want

[working jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/4uqFP/)

**HTML**

```
form
<input type="submit" id="go"/>
<p style="min-height:600px;"></p>
<div id="results">results</div>
<p style="min-height:300px;"></p>
```

**JS**

```
$("#go").click(function (e) {
    goToByScroll("results");
    e.preventDefault();
});

function goToByScroll(id) {
                var toMe = $("#" + id)
                $("html,body").animate({ scrollTop: toMe.offset().top }, "slow");
                toMe.addClass("hightlightResult");
                setTimeout(function () {
                    toMe.removeClass("hightlightResult", 1500);
                }, 500);
            }
```

Comment: This seems VERY promising, I just have a question.

Where do I place the JS portion ? Should I do it in an externam .js file, and link it, or place it inline somewhere.

Comment: that's really up to you. I would think that most people here at SO would suggest to put it in a seperate JS file. Doing this will keep your program [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself), help with being able to find it, and keep it maintained.

Comment: OK, I did it ( have it inline for the time being ) and it still doesn't work, there is no scroll functionality. Can you take a look at it, and help me work this out ?

Comment: My mistake, saved the local copy, not the live one. Check it now.

Comment: try disconnecting the button from the form or adding a separate button to try it out. this **should** work

Comment: I added a button with the id="go" and it still didn't yield the correct results... ( It's removed now, because I'm stupidly testing this all on a live server )

Comment: The button still appears to be of type: submit; could you please try disconnecting it from the form?

Comment: I tried adding <button id="go"> </button> and didn't get the desired results, I can't keep it online, because it's the live version.

Comment: can you add a test page to keep playing with it? also you can't have more then one element with the same id.

Answer (score 0):

maybe try delay() before it scrolls, because the content has to load before it can scroll anywhere.

Comment: Interesting thought, you may be onto something here. How can I accomplish this ?